# import external data into hdfs: is edge node a bottle neck?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm new to big data. I'm trying to ingest MongoDB collection into hdfs, and have choices of using mongoDB java API + HDFS java API, vs Spark MongoDB connector.

1. How are both approaches different? I checked Spark MongoDB connector source code, it also uses mongoDB java API for write to mongoDB, but uses sparkSession for read from mongoDB.
2. Since the MongoDB and HDFS cluster are different in our case, is the edge node acting as a staging area between MongoDB and HDFS cluster? If so, if the mongoDB collection too big, will edge node be a bottleneck? To generalize this question, when ingest external data sources (RDBMs, NoSQL etc) into HDFS, is the edge node always staging area?
3. Follow-up to Q2. Is there a way to connect HDFS data node directly to mongoDB server, skipping the edge node? For example, from mongoDB sharding partition to HDFS partition.

Appreciate your answer!

Comment: Hi! HDFS is the Hadoop Distributed File System. I don't think it will read data from any source, it can only provide a storage distributed system with high fault toletance. So you could use it as a file system to store your data. About the usage of Apache Spark to read from MongoDB and write into HDFS, maybe this is the best approach, because Spark leverages the distributed processing instead of single core processing, but you need to analyze your application and see what are your needings.

Comment: By "read" I mean to ingest data from external data source into HDFS. And do you know the answers to the questions?

Answer (score 1):

So, the high level answer to

> mongoDB java API + HDFS java API, vs Spark MongoDB connector

What you'll want to understand is that Spark isn't staging data on just the edge node. It runs in parallel. Uploading data in parallel, assuming the Mongo collection allows for that.

As compared to a direct Java API yourself (or even a collection dump), plus uploading, then yes, the edge node or wherever else is a bottleneck (and single point of failure)

An arguably better architecture involves using Debezium to stream the Mongo events out as individual records, into a Kafka topic, then you can process the events in real-time as they enter Kafka, optionally cleaning them, then send them to Hadoop, a graph database, search engine, etc (and Spark isn't required here)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it definitely helps a lot. We do have the option to use Kafka. 
But I still want to know a little more about how Spark does everything "in parallel" without all going through edge node. If it is too trouble for you to explain I'd appreciate you can point to somewhere I can learn in detail.

Comment: To me, the edge node is usually the only node exposed to external webs, so the mongoDB will all go through the edge data (physically) anyway whether spark is used or not. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @hawkssss Spark commands are submitted to the YARN ResourceManager and multiple Spark executor programs are distributed to the NodeManagers than usually run on each of the DataNodes. The edge-node doesn't need to be touched (you can usually bypass submitting Spark jobs from there, and they don't run there if using `--deploy-mode=cluster`). I don't know the internals of the SparkMongo reader to how it performs